# How to resolve "name 'imdb' is not defined" error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to create "*text classification with TensorFlow Hub: Movie reviews*" model. Below is my code:

```
import tensorflow as td
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

data = keras.datasets.imdb

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = data.load_data(num_words=10000)

print(train_data[1])

word_index = imdb.get_word_index()
```

when I executed this code, I receive `NameError: name 'imdb' is not defined` . How should I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

dataset, information = tfds.load('imdb_reviews/subwords8k', with_info=True,                  as_supervised=True)
train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset['train'], dataset['test']
```

Comment: thank you very for your helping hand. i recieve this error `ImportError: No module named tensorflow_datasets
`

Comment: If you are working locally, you have to install it -

pip install tensorflow-datasets

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write

```
data.get_word_index()
```

since you already imported the dataset by calling

```
keras.dataset.imdb
```

equal to data, it would be like writing it this way

```
word_index = keras.datasets.imdb.get_word_index()
```